# Проблема со шрифтами в Mozilla Firefox

Tags: css, шрифты

Подключаю шрифт, везде работает, но в Mozilla Firefox ошибка:

> downloadable font: no supported format found (font-family: "PT Sans"
>   style:normal weight:normal stretch:normal src index:3) source: (end of
>   source list)

```
/* cyrillic-ext */
@font-face {
  font-family: "PT Sans";
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 400;
  src: local('PT Sans'), local('PTSans-Regular'), url(../fonts/JX7MlXqjSJNjQvI4heMMGvY6323mHUZFJMgTvxaG2iE.woff2) format('woff2');
  unicode-range: U+0460-052F, U+20B4, U+2DE0-2DFF, U+A640-A69F;
}

/* cyrillic */
@font-face {
  font-family: "PT Sans";
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 400;
  src: local('PT Sans'), local('PTSans-Regular'), url(../fonts/vtwNVMP8y9C17vLvIBNZI_Y6323mHUZFJMgTvxaG2iE.woff2) format('woff2');
  unicode-range: U+0400-045F, U+0490-0491, U+04B0-04B1, U+2116;
}
```

Что делать?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Подключать во всех форматах и с нужными хаками:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: "JournalRegular";
    src: url("journal-webfont.eot");
    src: url("journal-webfont.eot?#iefix") format("embedded-opentype"),
         url("journal-webfont.woff") format("woff"),
         url("journal-webfont.ttf") format("truetype"),
         url("journal-webfont.svg#JournalRegular") format("svg");
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}
```

http://xiper.net/collect/html-and-css-tricks/typographics/font-face-non-standart-fonts-on-css

Comment: лол, с гугла как-то можно скачать архив со шрифтами нужного шрифта? А то сохранять по отдельности жестоко. https://www.google.com/fonts/

Comment: @ModaL, так оно же архивом и скачивается. Жмёшь add to collection, затем download и zip.

Comment: нашёл шрифт PT-Sans с другого сайта, подключил Вашим способом и всё заработало. Спасибо!

Answer (score 1):

Воспользуйтесь генератором: http://www.fontsquirrel.com/tools/webfont-generator
на выходе получите реально пуленепробиваемый синтаксис @font-face, полностью кроссбраузерный.